Bad internet connection only in video games (EndeavourOS)
I encounter internet connection issues only while playing video games (Tekken 8 and VRChat, GTA V online works fine). Outside the game, the internet connection is normal and stable even if it is running but the game itself have trouble connecting to the internet. In Windows 10 they work fine.
Behavior:

Tekken 8: slow loading speeds when internet is connected and
disconnections when the match is over. Demo works fine.
VRChat:Worlds and avatars downloads are slow, they stop at a certain
percentage or they don’t even start (stays at 0%).

I have tried:

Disabling the firewall
Changing to Proton Experimental, hotfix and GE Proton
Add gamemoderun %command% and  HOST_LC_ALL=_.UTF-8 %command%  in
Launch Options
Updating packages and rebooting the computer
Changing DNS from Google’s to Cloudflare’s

Hardware:

TUF GAMING B550-PLUS as motherboard
Ethernet connection
RX6600 as Graphics Card

Edit: Proton's log produced by PROTON_LOG=1
Steam.log
Edit 2: Issue also reported here Tekken 8 Unable to Connect to Other Players 

Emulated software is best effort. There's likely nothing to troubleshoot here.
